# How to make a pagination in PHP?

Tags: php, html, pagination

All I have is a number. Which is the number of rows. Now I need to create a pagination UI based on that number. Here is my code:

```
// for example
$rows_num = 23;

// limit
$per_page = 10;

// the number of pages
$pages_num = ceil($rows_num / $per_page);

if ( $pages_num  > 1 ) {
    $current_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

    $back_btn = $current_page != 0 ? "<a href='?page=$current_page-1' >back</a>" : null;
    $forward_btn = $pages_num > $current_page ? "<a href='?page=$current_page+1' >forward</a>" : null;
}
```

My code creates <kbd>back</kbd> and <kbd>forward</kbd> buttons of the pagination box. But I don't know how can I create such a thing:

```
// $pages_num = 5
1   2   3  ... 5

// $pages_num = 2
1   2

// $pages_num = 12
1   2   3   ...   12
```

See? I want to make 3 links of the first *(if exists)* and 1 link of the end *(if exists)*. Does anybody how can I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** `show 3 pages behind and one page ahead`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$rows_num = 50;
$per_page = 38;
$pages_num = ceil($rows_num / $per_page);
$current_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$current_page=$current_page>$pages_num ? $pages_num:$current_page; 

$counter=0;
$lastLink=($current_page-3) <= 1 ? 1 : $current_page-3;

for($x=$lastLink;$x<=$current_page;$x++)
{
    echo $button = "<a href='?page=".($x)."' >".($x)."</a>" ;
    echo "&nbsp;";
    $counter++;
    if($counter==4)
    {
        break;
    }
}
echo $button = $pages_num > $current_page ? "<a href='?page=".($current_page+1)."' >".($current_page+1)."</a>" : null;
```

**Solution 2:** This will add all page numbers links, as well as forward and backward buttons too.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$rows_num = 23;

// limit
$per_page = 10;

// the number of pages
$pages_num = ceil($rows_num / $per_page);

if ( $pages_num  > 1 ) 
{
    $current_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

    echo $back_btn = $current_page !=1 ? "<a href='?page=".($current_page-1)."' >back</a> " : null;

    for($x=0;$x<$pages_num;$x++)
    {
        echo $button = "<a href='?page=".($x+1)."' >".($x+1)."</a>" ;
        echo "&nbsp;";

    }
    echo $forward_btn = $pages_num != $current_page ? "<a href='?page=".($current_page+1)."' >forward</a>" : null;
}
```

Comment: @stack You can check my solution.. This will add page numbers, as well as forward and backward buttons too.

Comment: Your approach prints **all** page numbers .. I wanted 3 pages from the first and 1 page from the last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144760/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-stack).

Comment: @stack I have more optimized my solution 1, for your expected output, If you want, you can use that one.. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with for around your  rules of frontend needs. I tried to reproduce your need, but is scalable to many forms of designs with that algorithm:

```
    // for example
    $rows_num = 23;

    // limit
    $per_page = 10;

    // the number of pages
    $pages_num = ceil($rows_num / $per_page);

    if ( $pages_num  > 1 ) {
        $current_page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0;

     //your backward
    echo ($current_page > 1) ? "<a href='?page=$current_page-1' >back</a>" : null;
     for($i = $current_page; $i <= $pages_num; $i++){
        echo "<a href='?page=$i' >$i</a>";
        if ($i >= 3 && $i % 3) {
           echo '...&nbsp;',$pages_num;
           break;
        }
     }

       //your forward
       echo ($pages_num > $current_page) ? "<a href='?page=$current_page+1' >forward</a>" : null;

}
```